# Clear all annotations with cornerstone-tools

Tags: cornerstonejs

Using cornerstone-tools,
After I load a image, I start to draw some annotations such as angle, rectangle, arrow.

I´d like to know a method to clear  all annotations.
I try the next but no look

```
removeAll(element) {
      cornerstoneTools.state.tools.forEach(function (tool) {
        const toolState = cornerstoneTools.getToolState(element, tool.name)
        if (toolState) {
          // Modifying in a foreach? Probably not ideal
          cornerstoneTools.toolState.data.forEach(function (data) {
            cornerstoneTools.removeToolState(element, tool.name, data)
          })
        }
      })
      cornerstone.updateImage(element)
    },
```

Comment: Great question! Sometimes, the `removeToolState` function can be ambiguous. However, you can take a look on my answer to see some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can use the [`clearToolState`](https://tools.cornerstonejs.org/api/#clearToolState) function. You have several [examples](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/cornerstone-tools/functions/cornerstone-tools.clearToolState) and [issues](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools/issues/1193) concerning this problem, that you may follow. However, it seems a good option to use the [`clearToolState`](https://tools.cornerstonejs.org/api/#clearToolState) function in your case. The [`clearToolState`](https://tools.cornerstonejs.org/api/#clearToolState) function will remove all states from the state manager corresponding to the name and element of that tool.

Indeed, the documentation describes the [`clearToolState`](https://tools.cornerstonejs.org/api/#clearToolState) function as:

> Removes all `toolState` from the `toolStateManager` corresponding to the `toolName` and element.

It is also important to [understand how does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72704446/2371987) [1, 2] the `cornerstoneTool` store its values. Additionally, you can also follow [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72830534/2371987) when using a new tool or function.

## References

[1] Francisco Maria Calisto, Carlos Santiago, Nuno Nunes, and Jacinto C. Nascimento. 2021. Introduction of human-centric AI assistant to aid radiologists for multimodal breast image classification. International Journal of Human-Computer Studies 150, 102607. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijhcs.2021.102607

[2] Francisco Maria Calisto, Nuno Nunes, and Jacinto C. Nascimento. 2020. BreastScreening. Proceedings of the International Conference on Advanced Visual Interfaces. https://doi.org/10.1145/3399715.3399744